# I have a "Ticket" which needs to have state remembered across a life cycle

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, state

I have a "Ticket", it has features such as Name and UUID etc... 
It has a selection state. The selection is remembered across activities. So returning to the recycler view means it "remains" selected (no, not actually... it's re-selected via coding magic)
It has a "New" and "Existing" state
It can transition from "New" to "Existing" mid lifecycle. (Lifecycle of the ticket, not lifecycle of the activity)

I have created a state engine, but this seems to be the wrong pattern.
The purpose of the class in the example below is to decouple the activities/components.

I know that the following example does not look like a state engine, which is why I'm asking this question, an actual state engine doesn't seem to fit my needs.

What is the recommended way to handle the following example:

```
public class TicketStateEngine {

    private static int mCurrentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition = -1;
    private static LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private static boolean mIsNewTicket;

    public static boolean isIsNewTicket() {
        return mIsNewTicket;
    }

    public static void setIsNewTicket(boolean isNewTicket) {
        mIsNewTicket  = isNewTicket;
    }

    public static void setLinearLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    public static int getCurrentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition() {
        return mCurrentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition;
    }

    public static void setCurrentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition(int currentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition) {
        mCurrentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition = currentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition;
    }

    public static void scrollToSelected() {
        try {
            mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(mCurrentSelectedRecyclerViewPosition, 0);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("NullPointerException", "Make sure a Linear Layout manger is set for TicketStateEngine");
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how you are sharing the tickets between activities, but if you use Room or some other database, I would suggest storing the `isNew` status in your Ticket model, that way the status would be stored in the DB and could be easily updated.

Comment: thanks @IvánEsparza, I'm Using MVVM with a Repo (eventually will serialize in some way)... So yep can do that. Selection state is the other key piece of the puzzle, any ideas?

Comment: I just read about storing state in the ViewModel, what do people think about this. Should my ViewModel hold the selected item index for the current selected RecyclerView item?

Comment: Not really sure about storing the index, I would store the UUID instead, that way if the list changes at some point, you could restore the selection state with the same selected ticket.

Comment: @IvánEsparza I have thought about that. At the moment the index provides easy access to the position. Later if I need a more robust way, I'll implement a search for UUID, but it's extra work that isn't needed in the current iteration. Cheer though :)